# insufficient privileges cloning record

Tags: permissions, clone

Would anyone know why a person who can create,edit and delete a record gets an  "insufficient privileges" when cloning the very same record and how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I think he don't have owner of the record and missing view all, modify all permission.

Comment: I gave the profile modify all on the object but it didn't help

Comment: You should check sharing setting of the object and compare sharing of the record owner and this person.

Comment: Can you give a bit more info how to do this?